# Laravel Excel retorna todos campos null al leer celda con email

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-excel

Tal cual he realizado pruebas y me he dado cuenta que es al leer la celda del documento este es mi documento .xlsx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema viene que cuando lleno estas celdas con numeros/links/emails ya que NO los reconoce y me lanza el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `rol`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, $2y$10$3.qj7GcaplGZrYr5.X2Eyu.gEhwZVE97BLdquVa9bvyIr7VRmhA/C, 2020-04-17 16:09:21, 2020-04-17 16:09:21))

Les dejo los codigos correspondientes.

Modelo

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;

        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password', 'rol'
        ];
}
```

Import

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\{ToModel, WithHeadingRow};

class UsuariosImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row['nombre'],
            'email' => $row['correo'],
            'rol' => $row['perfil'],
            'password' => Hash::make($row['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Controlador

```
...
    public function importCentro(Request $request){
            Excel::import(new UsuariosImport, request()->file('centroxlsx'));
            Excel::import(new CentrosImport, request()->file('centroxlsx'));
...
```

Gracias

Comment: Pues parece ser que la columna name esta vacía y tu tabla users no acepta que este valor sea vacío

Comment: Exactamente no te puedo decir que está mal pero te recomiendo que hagas algunas verificaciones en tus archivos: 1. Verifica que el formato del archivo excel sea el correcto, por ejemplo que no sea un csv con la extensión XLS o XLSX 2. Verifica el contenido de $row en tu clase UsuariosImport

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con lo que marca tu error es que en el archivo que importas tienes campos que no pueden ser nulos, estos debes verificarlos en tu base de datos, ya sea para permitir que ese campo sea o no nulo.